# Coco.names dataset with text descriptions of objects

Tags: python, dataset, tf-idf, coco

I'm doing a personal project where I'm using the "coco.names" dataset. The idea is that the program can recognise an object from this dataset by its text description. To do this I need a dataset that has a description of each of the "coco.names" objects. But I still can't find a dataset with text descriptions of these objects. Perhaps some of you know where I can get it? Thanks for any help.

I collect the data for TF-IDF.

I tried to collect the data myself, but it takes a long time and the data set is not that big.